# lua - print in bold text

Tags: fonts, lua

In this lua function, I would like to print the device and temp values in bold. Not sure how this would work since the report model is concat.

```
function getmail(index)
if ((last_mail == nil) or (now - last_mail > set_timer)) then 

report_model = [[
Device: %s
Device Location: %s
___________________________________

Current Temperature: %d F
Temperature Limit: (%d-%d F)
Current Humidity Level: %d %%
Humidity Limit: (%d-%d %%)

**Time Recorded at: %s**]]


d = devicetable[index]

report_content = report_model:format(device_name, description,
      temperature, t_under_limit, t_over_limit,
      humidity, h_under_limit, h_over_limit,
      os.date())
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Lua, and everything to do with the device you're printing to, so we'll need to know what that device is.

Answer (score 2):

Lua knows nothing about fonts or displays. Its IO library, like C's, knows only about streams of bytes/characters.

> the report model is concat

Meaning what? The output is concatenated to a text file? A plain text file doesn't support putting individual words in bold. If your output is HTML/RTF/etc. -- some format that supports markup -- you'd have options.  If your output is a terminal, some of those on some platforms support [escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), so you'd have options there, too.

Bottom line, this isn't a Lua question. You need to re frame the question in terms of your platform and output mechanism.

Comment: The output is an email sent via smtp.

Comment: Then you can use [html](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_formatting.asp) to markup the text, then [set the appropriate headers when sending the message](http://www.codestore.net/store.nsf/unid/EPSD-587VVX).

Comment: ahh, thanks! but how would that work since I dont want everything in the body bold, just the values?

Comment: Did you click the links in my last comment? The first one in particular. For example: `Device: <b>%s</b>`.  In short, you need to learn some extremely basic HTML. To learn what you need should take about 10 minutes.

Comment: yes, I did, I understand what you are saying but the lua script will just print out the whole thing:  Device: <b>Device #1 - Temp</b>

Comment: No clue what you're asking. If you want part of it in bold, use the bold tag on that part.